# VBA Find specific keywords and store formula on cells of selected rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I got the following data in my table and my requirements is to look after the word `Plan/Actual Input DOC Qty`,`Actual Daily Mortality`,`Forecast Qty` which got a lot of occurrences and I'm going to store a formula in each cell of their Row.

[image: My Table]

I got the following code and I am not quite sure if this is the right one though because i got a lot of errors on it. Please have a look and correct me if I'm wrong. Any Help will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim forecastQty As String
Dim Rng As Range


With Rows("1:1")
forecastQty = Criteria1:=Array("Plan/Actual Input DOC Qty","Actual Daily Mortality","Forecast Qty")
  Set Rng = .Find(what:=forecastQty, _
  after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  lookat:=xlWhole, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumn, _
  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
  ActiveCell.Address.Select
Else
MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the errors you get, and the rows on which you get them, so that we are better able to assist you.

Comment: @Luuklag It says syntax error `forecastQty = Criteria1:=Array("Plan/Actual Input DOC Qty","Actual Daily Mortality","Forecast Qty")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this another way of searching specific keywords.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As String, y As String, z As String, PO As String


i = 2
Do Until Sheets("your sheet name").Cells(i, 1) = ""

x = "Plan"
y = "Actual"
z = "Forecast"

PO = Sheets("your sheet name").Cells(i, 4)

    If InStr(1, PO, x, 1) > 0 Then

        'Do what you want

    ElseIf InStr(1, PO, y, 1) > 0 Then

        'Do what you want

    ElseIf InStr(1, PO, z, 1) > 0 Then

    'Do what you want

    End If

i = i + 1
Loop
```

This will loop through the data and search for a specific keyword. In your case;

```
Plan/Actual Input = Plan
Actual Daily Mortality = Actual
Forecast Qty = Forecast
```

The code will search if a row of column D contains the specific keyword and you can put your formula on the     if else block. Note that *INSTR* is a function where you can search a substring from a string.